# What is the difference between %0.2lf and %.2lf as printf placeholders?

Tags: c, format, width, printf

I am aware that putting any number of `0`'s before the width of the placeholder implements zero-padding. For example, `printf("%02d", 6);` prints `06`.

But what does putting a single `0` before the precision of the placeholder do? For example, for both `printf("%0.2lf", 0.123);` and `printf("%.2lf", 0.123);`, the output is `0.12`.

If it does nothing, is there a preferred format?

Comment: @teppic, 0 does not mean a minimum width of 0 (what kind of useless information is that?). 0 is a flag meaning 0-pad instead of space-pad. I can see from your answer that you already know that, so please stop saying it means "minimum width of 0" because it doesn't.

Comment: @Shahbaz - I was talking about this specific case, but as it seems to be causing confusion I've removed the comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are "equivalent". If you were to use "%07.2", then it would make a difference, by adding extra zeros on the front.

Edit: Originally had "%04.2", which of course doesn't make any difference, because a float with two decimals is always 4 wide anyway.

Comment: Isn't it (the '0'-padding) ignored for floating point if there's an precision specified explicitly?

Comment: At least when testing in gcc on Linux, zero padding "works". I'm pretty sure that's part of the standard, but I'm a little lazy, so I'll wait for someone else to point out that I'm wrong.

Comment: @DyP - the zero padding is to the left, e.g. 0003.12. It doesn't work for zeros after the decimal point.

Comment: @teppic C standard says (C99 and n1256) that in `"%0"`, the `0` is interpreted as a flag, meaning "use 0 for padding". But there's no min field width specified (between the `0` and `.`), therefore, it's effectively _ignored_. I got my former info from cppreference, but it's a bit different from what the Standard says.

Comment: @teppic No it's NOT taken as a minimum width. It's taken as a flag indicating "use `'0'` for padding instead of `' '`", that's why Mats is correct in that `"%07.2f"` being different from `"%7.2f"`. In `"%0.2f"`, no minimum width is specified, therefore min width is per default 0.

Comment: @DyP - it *doesn't matter*. They amount to the exact same thing when 0 is by itself.

Comment: @teppic I agree it _doesn't matter here_, but your statement is not precise ("0 by itself specifies a minimum width of 0") and there's a subtlety in that e.g. `"%0s"` leads to undefined behaviour as the `0` is taken as a flag.

Comment: @DyP - I'm speaking about the specific question, not in general.

Answer (score 11):

`%3.2f  //(print as a floating point at least 3 wide and a precision of 2)` 

`%0.2lf       //(print as a floating point at least 0 wide and a precision of 2)`


`%.2lf       //(print as a floating point at least 0(default) wide and a precision of 2)`

Answer (score 3):

These examples should show the difference:

`"%0.2lf", 0.123` -> `0.12` (zero padded min. width of 0, 2 decimal places).

`"%6.2lf", 0.123` -> `__0.12` (space padded min. width of 6, 2 decimal places).

`"%06.2lf", 0.123` -> `000.12` (zero padded min. width of 6, 2 decimal places).

`"%0.6lf", 0.123` -> `0.123000` (min width of 0, 6 decimal places).

The first zero specifies zero padding, followed by the minimum width, which has a default of 0. Thus it is effectively ignored by itself (since you cannot pad 0 width).

---

Incidentally, the correct form is `%f`, not `%lf` for `printf`.

Comment: While we're at it, the integer promotion rule (See C11, 6.5.2.2.6) forces the floating point value to be cast to `double`. This means that both `float` and `double` reach `printf` as `double` and therefore `%f` and `%lf` both expect `double` and therefore are the same. This is why also you never see `%hd` because it works exactly the same as `%d`. Additionally this is why you don't need to cast a char to int if it is given to `%d`. Side note: this is not the same for `scanf`, since `char *` for example doesn't get promoted to `int *`!

Comment: @Shahbaz - as a side point, yes. If I remember correctly `%lf` is allowed in C99 but the `l` is completely ignored - though %lf may cause problems for older compilers.

Answer (score 1):

> Blockquote

Basically when we `% w.p f` for output `w` refers to the minimum number of position to be use for displaying the value and `p` refers to the number of digit after decimal point.
`%3.2f` floating point having 3 wide and 2 number after decimal

`%0.2f`floating point at least 0 wide and  2 number after decimal

`%.2f` floating point at least 0(default) wide and a precision of 2)

But don't misunderstand about the 0 width if you use `%0.2f` it can auto adjust its minimum width.